# AWS IoT rule - timestamp for Elasticsearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-iot

Have a bunch of IoT devices (ESP32) which publish a JSON object to `things/THING_NAME/log` for general debugging (to be extended into other topics with values in the future).

Here is the IoT rule which kind of works.

```
{
  "sql": "SELECT *, parse_time(\"yyyy-mm-dd'T'hh:mm:ss\", timestamp()) AS timestamp, topic(2) AS deviceId FROM 'things/+/stdout'",
  "ruleDisabled": false,
  "awsIotSqlVersion": "2016-03-23",
  "actions": [
    {
      "elasticsearch": {
        "roleArn": "arn:aws:iam::xxx:role/iot-es-action-role",
        "endpoint": "https://xxxx.eu-west-1.es.amazonaws.com",
        "index": "devices",
        "type": "device",
        "id": "${newuuid()}"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm not sure how to set `@timestamp` inside Elasticsearch to allow time based searches.

Maybe I'm going about this all wrong, but it almost works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@timestamp` is just a convention as the `@` prefix is the default prefix for Logstash generated fields. Because you are not using Logstash as a middleman between IoT and Elasticsearch, you don't have a default mapping for @timestamp.

But basically, it is just a name, so call it what you want, the only thing that matters is that you declare it as a timestamp field in the mappings section of the Elasticsearch index.

If for some reason you still need it to be called `@timestamp`, you can either `SELECT` it with that prefix right away in the `AS` section (might be an issue with IoT's sql restrictions, not sure):

```
SELECT *, parse_time(\"yyyy-mm-dd'T'hh:mm:ss\", timestamp()) AS @timestamp, topic(2) AS deviceId FROM 'things/+/stdout'
```

Or you use the [copy_to](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/copy-to.html) functionality when declaring you're mapping:

```
PUT devices/device
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "timestamp": {
                "type": "date",
                "copy_to": "@timestamp" 
            },
            "@timestamp": {
                "type": "date",
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah nice one I deleted the index and recreated it with timestamp.type = date and it's all working now. You can't put the @ in the IoT SQL SELECT no matter what quotes you wrap it in.

Comment: Yeah figured that they will probably ban certain types of characters. Well, at least you've got Elastic for the rescue. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Elasticsearch can recognize date strings matching `dynamic_date_formats`.
The following format is automatically mapped as a `date` field in AWS Elasticsearch 7.1:

```
SELECT *, parse_time("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss", timestamp()) AS timestamp FROM 'events/job/#'
```

This approach does not require to create a preconfigured index, which is important for dynamically created indexes, e.g. with daily rotation for logs:

```
devices-${parse_time("yyyy.MM.dd", timestamp(), "UTC")}
```

According to [elastic.co documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.x/dynamic-field-mapping.html#date-detection),

> The default value for dynamic_date_formats is:
>
> [ "strict_date_optional_time","yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss Z||yyyy/MM/dd Z"]